# Caller ID in Plivo

Tags: api, plivo

I am using Plivo API for calling and need to get my call to display a valid Caller ID Number.
I am using a Callback URL :

```
<Response>
    <Record action="http://173.255.193.124/~ramacrm/CallWithPlivo/vtigercrm/plivo/call/recording" startOnDialAnswer="true" redirect="false" callerId="+9198102****"/>
    <Dial>
        <Number>+91880231****</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong as I am working on this referring the [Plivo API Documentation - Here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/dial/)

Comment: You need to put the callerId param in the Dial section.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the CallerId in the Dial verb, so:

```
<Dial action="your_action_url" 
callbackUrl="your_callback_url"
callerId="441903xxxxxx" method="POST" timeout="25"><Number>4479xxxxxx</Number></Dial>
```